# What do you think about this extending function?

Tags: javascript, extend

I've created my own extending function, but I´m not sure if it is good to use it. Maybe it is slow or does things that I don't expect.

Look at this:

```
Object.prototype.Extend = function(){                           
    this.__proto__.__proto__ = new (arguments[0].bind.apply(arguments[0],arguments))();
}

function A(a){
    this.a = a;
}

function B(a,b){
    this.Extend(A,a);
    this.b = b;
}
```

Tests with it were wonderful, but I don´t know if this **proto**._*proto*_ thing is a really good idea.

Let me know your opinion. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like calling it successively to extend from two different classes would not work very well.

Comment: @Pointy, I've never seen multiple inheritance work well in JS if you want instanceOf to work.

Comment: @Juan Mendes well it's a pretty common idiom to extend "into" an object from multiple "layers" of sources:  global defaults, contextual defaults, explicit settings ...

Comment: @Pointy: which is not what OP's doing, OP's setting up the prototype chain, albeit in a poor way/

Comment: Yes, that's kind-of my point :-)  I get what it's doing, and (for many reasons) I think it's not a good idea. That first comment was just the first issue I thought of (well, the *first* thing was that "__proto__" is not a standard, or at least not universally supported).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

__proto__ is not standard, only works in firefox.

Also, you're setting up inheritance for every instantiation, which is not ideal since you're repeating that work.

You're invoking the constructor just to setup inheritance

Look at my post for further descriptions and other problems with your pattern. http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. It doesn't matter for me if this is not a standard conform solution. I'm developing Chrome Apps, which don't care about other browsers. In chrome, this works really well, too! In your post, you add the functions either outline or in a sub object. I don't like this synatx, because I often use private functions and variables in public functions. So in my opinion, inline is the better way.

Comment: Sure, if that's your use. However, other options, like what I suggested, would not tie your code down to a platform and let you more easily share your code. Also, I mentioned other problems with your approach. It will still work, just not as elegant, like I said, your code is being run when it doesn't need to.